# __attribute__((weak)) for typedefs

Tags: c, overriding, typedef, weak

With `__attribute__((weak))` I can declare a function which will be overridden by a function with the same name, but without `__attribute__((weak))` parameter. Is there a way to do something similar with `typedefs`in C? For example, I would declare a "weak" typedef in my template library:

```
my_weak typedef int myType_t;
```

Then in a new file i do:

```
typedef float myType_t
```

So `myType_t` is a float, not an int. I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Why would you need that? Types are visible only in their scope. If you don't like some type - don't include it's definition...

Comment: "Weak" ultimately applies to symbols, which are interpreted by the linker.  Typedefs are not a concept that's exposed to the linker...

Comment: This code is for an MCU. I am creating a generic library. In that library one can use uart module or not. In the struct there is a pointer to the uart structure that is a typedef. The typedef is only visible if uart lib is visible. It is not visible (not added to the project) if one uses no uart variant. But the pointer has to remain in the struct (even though unused). SInce I the typedef of that struct is now unknown, it wont compile. Thats why I thought I could use some default dummy typedef for this occasion.

Comment: That's probably not the best design if it is raising such a questions. Just us #ifdef mytype_t ... #endif around the field in the structure.

Comment: I would do this, but I dont know what statement to put in this `#ifdef`. In the code, I have no knowledge either the module uses uart at compile time.

Comment: The previous comment is not correct, sorry. `ifdef` is not working with type names. But your uart header can define some symbols like "`USE_UART`".

Comment: I figured out that when the project files are generated with uart module, a file `uart.h` is added. In that file, like in any *.h file an `ifdef` like this is added: #ifndef __usart_H #define #ifndef __usart_H. So I have a symbol __usart_H. I then check if it is not defines, define it: typedef uint32_t UART_HandleTypeDef; In the h file this resides, in the struct definion a member of this type is recognised but not in the code, I am not sure why.

Comment: The multiple-inclusion guard macro in your header is not suitable for discerning whether a given feature has been selected.  It tells you whether that header has already been included, which is an altogether different thing.  If the header file is not even present when the project is not configured to use it, then there must be some mechanism to determine whether the sources try to `#include` it at all.  THAT's what you want to hook.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes i know that it is used for avoiding multi including, but it seems to work... It does define something I can see in the code doesnt it?

Comment: I found a better way. When the project is generated there is a header file with defines that het uncommented if a module is used, for example: `HAL_UART_MODULE_ENABLED`. Using this information I can form an `#ifdef`. Thank you for answers.